# Travis deploy based on matrix parameters

Tags: travis-ci, release, release-management, github-release

I have a travis job that runs on both Linux and OSX, which I would like to be able to use to deploy *different build artefacts for each platform* to github releases. My `.travis.yml` file currently looks something like this:

```
language: rust

cache: cargo

os:
  - linux
  - osx

rust: 
  - stable
  - beta
  - nightly 

script: 
  - cargo build --release -vv
  - cargo test --release --all -vv

matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - rust: nightly
  fast_finish: true

deploy:
  - provider: releases
    skip_cleanup: true
    api_key:
      secure: <encrypted key here, removed for brevity> 
    before_deploy: 
      - cargo install cargo-deb
      - cargo deb --no-build --no-strip
      - ./scripts/package_linux.sh .
    file_glob: true
    file: 
      - "target/debian/ellington_0.1.0_amd64.deb"
      - "releases/*_linux.zip"
    on:
      tags: true
      os: linux
      rust: stable
```

I assume that I add a second deploy step (e.g. see below), but I can't find any documentation on *how* to do this, let alone whether it's even possible. There is extensive documentation on deploying to *multiple* providers, but not on deploying multiple times to the same providers on different platforms.

```
  - provider: releases
    skip_cleanup: true
    api_key:
      secure: <encrypted key here, removed for brevity> 
    before_deploy: 
      - ./scripts/package_osx.sh .
    file_glob: true
    file: 
      - "releases/*_osx.zip"
    on:
      tags: true
      os: osx
      rust: stable
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7761) link!

The gist of it is yes, you were on the right track and you can define multiple deployments like so:

```
deploy:
    - provider: releases
      api_key: "<deploy key>"
      file:
        - "target/release.deb"
      skip_cleanup: true
      on:
        tags: true

    - provider: releases
      api_key: "<deploy key>"
      file:
        - "target/release.dmg"
      skip_cleanup: true
      on:
        tags: true

    - provider: releases
      etc...
```

Relevant documentation for this feature can also be found [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#examples-of-conditional-deployment). approximately halfway through the conditional deployment section.